# Trying to call getActivity(), using AppCompat, from an Inner OnLongClickListener Class

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development and just working through a series of tutorials/labs. The one I am currently working through is located here: https://sites.google.com/site/androidappcoursev3/labs/lab-3

I have deviated a bit from the lab, and am using AppCompat rather than ActionBarSherlock.

The current section I am on requires the use of Contextual Action Mode to create a menu to delete jokes (4.2.2 of the lab). The Lab mentions that the way to implement this is located here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

Here is the code they have suggested, for ease:

```
someView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
// Called when the user long-clicks on someView
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    if (mActionMode != null) {
        return false;
    }

    // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
    mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
    view.setSelected(true);
    return true;
}
```

});

The Lab also mentions that getActivity() is not available, because they use ActionBarSherlock, and gives a hint as such. I think the hint is leading to the fact that you should use getSherlockActivity() instead.

Using AppCompat, I cannot figure out how to do this.

My code is below:

```
 package edu.calpoly.android.lab3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdvancedJokeList extends ActionBarActivity
{

protected static final String TAG = "lab3sahil";

// Filter Options
protected static final int FILTER_SHOW_ALL = Joke.LIKE | Joke.DISLIKE
        | Joke.UNRATED;
protected static final int FILTER_LIKE = Joke.LIKE;
protected static final int FILTER_DISLIKE = Joke.DISLIKE;
protected static final int FILTER_UNRATED = Joke.UNRATED;

// Contextual Action Mode
protected ActionMode m_action_mode;
protected ActionMode.Callback action_mode_callback;

/** Contains the name of the Author for the jokes. */
protected String m_strAuthorName;

/** Contains the list of Jokes the Activity will present to the user. */
protected ArrayList<Joke> m_arrJokeList;

/**
 * Contains the list of filtered Jokes the Activity will present to the
 * user.
 */
protected ArrayList<Joke> m_arrFilteredJokeList;

/** Adapter used to bind an AdapterView to List of Jokes. */
protected JokeListAdapter m_jokeAdapter;

/** ViewGroup used for maintaining a list of Views that each display Jokes. */
protected ListView m_vwJokeLayout;

/**
 * EditText used for entering text for a new Joke to be added to
 * m_arrJokeList.
 */
protected EditText m_vwJokeEditText;

/**
 * Button used for creating and adding a new Joke to m_arrJokeList using the
 * text entered in m_vwJokeEditText.
 */
protected Button m_vwJokeButton;

/** Menu used for filtering Jokes. */
protected Menu m_vwMenu;

/**
 * Background Color values used for alternating between light and dark rows
 * of Jokes. Add a third for text color if necessary.
 */
protected int m_nDarkColor;
protected int m_nLightColor;
protected int m_nCurrentBGColor;

protected int m_nTextColor;

/**
 * Context-Menu MenuItem IDs. IMPORTANT: You must use these when creating
 * your MenuItems or the tests used to grade your submission will fail.
 * These are commented out for now.
 */
// protected static final int FILTER = Menu.FIRST;
// protected static final int FILTER_LIKE = SubMenu.FIRST;
// protected static final int FILTER_DISLIKE = SubMenu.FIRST + 1;
// protected static final int FILTER_UNRATED = SubMenu.FIRST + 2;
// protected static final int FILTER_SHOW_ALL = SubMenu.FIRST + 3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initLayout();
    initAddJokeListeners();

    // Get Resources
    Resources resources = this.getResources();
    String[] jokeResources = resources.getStringArray(R.array.jokeList);
    m_nDarkColor = resources.getColor(R.color.dark);
    m_nLightColor = resources.getColor(R.color.light);
    m_nCurrentBGColor = m_nDarkColor;

    m_nTextColor = resources.getColor(R.color.text);

    m_strAuthorName = resources.getString(R.string.author_name);

    m_arrJokeList = new ArrayList<Joke>();
    m_arrFilteredJokeList = new ArrayList<Joke>();
    m_jokeAdapter = new JokeListAdapter(this, m_arrFilteredJokeList);
    m_vwJokeLayout.setAdapter(m_jokeAdapter);

    for (String joke : jokeResources)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Adding new joke: " + joke);
        addJoke(new Joke(joke, m_strAuthorName));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.submenu_like:
        applyFilter(FILTER_LIKE);
        return true;
    case R.id.submenu_dislike:
        applyFilter(FILTER_DISLIKE);
        return true;
    case R.id.submenu_unrated:
        applyFilter(FILTER_UNRATED);
        return true;
    case R.id.submenu_show_all:
        applyFilter(FILTER_SHOW_ALL);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * Method is used to encapsulate the code that initializes and sets the
 * Layout for this Activity.
 */
protected void initLayout()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.advanced);

    this.m_vwJokeLayout = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.JokeListViewGroup);
    this.m_vwJokeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newJokeEditText);
    this.m_vwJokeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addJokeButton);

    // Contextual Action Mode
    action_mode_callback = new ActionMode.Callback()
    {
        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was
        // called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionmenu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown.
        // Always called after onCreateActionMode
        // However, may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.menu_remove:
                Toast.makeText(AdvancedJokeList.this, "Removed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
        {
            m_action_mode = null;
        }
    };



    //Set your ListView to have an onItemLongClickListener
    m_vwJokeLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
        {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v)
            {
                if (m_action_mode != null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                //Start the CAB using the ACtionMode.Callback
                m_action_mode = getActivity().startActionMode(action_mode_callback);
                v.setSelected(true);
                return true;

            }
        }
    );
}

/**
 * Method is used to encapsulate the code that initializes and sets the
 * Event Listeners which will respond to requests to "Add" a new Joke to the
 * list.
 */
protected void initAddJokeListeners()
{
    m_vwJokeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            // Create joke string
            String joke = m_vwJokeEditText.getText().toString();
            if (joke != null && !joke.equals(""))
            {
                // Reset Joke EditText Box
                m_vwJokeEditText.setText("");

                // Add Joke
                addJoke(new Joke(joke, m_strAuthorName));

                // Hide Soft Keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        m_vwJokeEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Method used for encapsulating the logic necessary to properly add a new
 * Joke to m_arrJokeList, and display it on screen.
 * 
 * @param joke
 *            The Joke to add to list of Jokes.
 */
protected void addJoke(Joke joke)
{

    // Add joke to Joke List
    m_arrJokeList.add(joke);
    m_arrFilteredJokeList.add(joke);
    m_jokeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

protected void applyFilter(int submenu_option)
{
    // Clear previous filter
    this.m_arrFilteredJokeList.clear();

    // Apply filter
    for (Joke joke : this.m_arrJokeList)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,
                "Value: " + String.valueOf(submenu_option)
                        + String.valueOf(joke.getRating()));
        if (joke.getRating() == submenu_option
                | submenu_option == FILTER_SHOW_ALL)
        {
            this.m_arrFilteredJokeList.add(joke);
        }
    }

    // Update Adapter
    m_jokeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

For help with navigation, my code (which resembles the code pasted above) is located in initLayout.

The error I am getting is the following: "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new View.OnLongClickListener(){}"

I have tried the following:

```
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).startActionMode(action_mode_callback);
((AdvancedJokeList)getActivity()).startActionMode(action_mode_callback);
ActionBarActivity.getActivity().startActionMode(action_mode_callback);
AdvancedJokeList.getActivity().startActionMode(action_mode_callback);
getActionBarActivity.startActionMode(action_mode_callback);
```

None of these approaches have worked.

Any help and guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are already in an `Activity` so simply call `startActionMode(..)`. `getActivity()` is used to get a reference to the `Activity` in a **Fragment**.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. For anybody who comes across this later and is having a similar problem following those tutorials, the next step is to change `startActionMode(...)` to `startSupportActionMode(...)`. The problem I have now is that the ActionMenu is not showing up. I think it is because I am not supposed to set the OnLongClickListener to m_vwLayout. The Action Menu is meant to appear when you long click the individual JokeView elements, but since you can arbitrarily create more JokeViews, I'm not sure what View object you set the OnClickListener to.

Comment: Did you checked if the long click listener is triggered? Make sure that your row view sets its focusable views (like `Buttons`, `ImageButtons`) to non focusable(by adding the `android:focusable="false"` property for those views).

Comment: Thanks. Changed the focusability of the items, which led me to realise the LongClickListener was not being triggered. The main problem was that I was not using an OnItemLongClickListener. I was using a OnLongClickListener. The good news is that since this was such a time consuming small mistake, I'm never going to make it again... hopefully :). Thanks again!

Comment: @DashAnimal can you share that the line what you did